# SUM, QUERY и пустые ячейки в Google Sheets работают не корректно

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Нужно отфильтровать данные с помощью query в googlesheets.

Не сумирует ячейки с значением пустыми значениями.

Знает ли кто как решить данную пробему? Как вариант вбить во все пустые ячейки нули, но это не то решение которое ожидается. Можно ли как то решить проблему без нулей в пустых ячейках?

[Ссылка на таблицу](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lge-KXVC493dSy3K7PM9zmBq6o8G6Lm1XxxqpqXQs64/edit?usp=sharing)

Фомула

```
=query(
  'исходная'!A1:AK;
  "select sum(I)+sum(J)+sum(K)
   where (B='Виктор' AND month(C) = month(date '2010-02-01') AND year(C) = year(date '2020-02-01')) 
   group by B
   label sum(I)+sum(J)+sum(K)''";
   0
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного упростил ваш пример, т.к. некоторые части запроса отношения к делу не имеют. [Моя Таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mBiKuh5l_jSpQLeTyRu4nQK1L3iWTX-smBxwCUFfDGo/edit?usp=sharing)

Есть некоторые данные. Важно обратить внимание, что ячейки могут содержать не только пустые значения, но и текст. Сами значения, вероятно, тоже могут быть текстом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если использовать формулу [QUERY](https://contributor.pw/tags/query/), то результат будет неожиданным

```
=QUERY(
  'Данные'!A1:AK;
  "select B, sum(I)+sum(J)+sum(K) group by B label sum(I)+sum(J)+sum(K)'Сумма'";
  1
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[QUERY](https://contributor.pw/tags/query/) требует однозначности в типах данных. Поэтому, если мы можем привести неизвестные типы к 0, то можно исползовать [VALUE](https://contributor.pw/tags/value/) и [IFERROR](https://contributor.pw/tags/iferror/) для подготовки массива данных.

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA({'Данные'!A1:H\IFERROR(VALUE('Данные'!I1:AK);0)});
  "select Col2, sum(Col9)+sum(Col10)+sum(Col11) group by Col2 label sum(Col9)+sum(Col10)+sum(Col11)'Сумма'";
  1
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, это то, что надо.